# Listview start performing automatically

Tags: android, listview

I want to develop an app where I will use listview.And every row include some information as well as media player for audio. And there will be a button as well for media player.When I press the button listview will start operating from index 0 and also start playing music. And it runs through untill I press the pause button.So it means starting from index 0 to the last index of listview. How can I do this? Is it possible. Thank you.

Comment: Didn't start yet. Just searching whether it is possible or not! And then I found an app on playstore which performing the exact same thing which I want to built. Didn't find anything specific. So just posted here.

Answer (score 0):

This is really easy with a recyclerView plus an AsyncTask and a ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor:

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground( Void... params ) {
    schedule();
    return null;
}

void schedule() {
    mExecutor.schedule( () -> {
        // do your calculation here like the scroll speed and conditions
        // Example: if the list item has height of 100px and the audio also has length 100 seconds, that means you have to scroll for 1px in every second

        int scrollPx = calculate();
        publishProgress(scrollPx);
        if ( !isCancelled() ) {
           schedule();
        }
    }, mScrollDelay, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS );
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate( Integer... values ) {
    recyclerView.scrollBy( 0, values[0] );
}
```

Comment: will it scroll the listview as it moves to next index.

Comment: I didn't read your question properly, but I updated my answer.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html